# How to add secondary_y axis to plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to figure out how to add a ***secondary_y***  axis on the right hand side of this chart (see image below).  I have this code that generates the chart:

```
   %matplotlib inline
    %pylab inline
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    mpl.style.use('default')
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 5))
    ax.set_title('Chart'.format('default'), color='C6')
    ax.set_xlabel('Date', fontsize=12)
    ax.set_ylabel('Price', fontsize=12)
    ax.plot(allstocks['date'], allstocks['msft'], label='msft')
    ax.plot(allstocks['date'], allstocks['ibm'], label='ibm')
    ax.legend()
```

I am looking for msft stock prices to be the secondary y axis, so that would be ***secondary_y = ["msft"]***.  However, I don't how to incorporate that into the above code.   Can you help?

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the [example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/two_scales.html) in the documentation for this?

Comment: I just did.  Looks like this will solve my problem.  Thanks for the quick response.